# MySQL Replication: MASTER_LOG_POS never changes

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a Master / Slave Setup in production and from time to time I add or remove a slave and recently I also removed the master and promoted a former slave to new master.

This procedure usually involves dumping my master DB like so:

`mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2 -A  > /data/dump.sql`

and then reading the MySQL master log position from the dump like so:

`head dump.sql -n80 | grep "MASTER_LOG_POS"`

The output is something like

`-- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000036', MASTER_LOG_POS=107;`

(Source: http://plusbryan.com/mysql-replication-without-downtime)

Now as I have done this a dozen times I noticed that while the MASTER_LOG_FILE changes, the value for MASTER_LOG_POS is always 107 and never changes even though I have created new dumps from the master every time I add a new slave, and the dumps are weeks apart. This seems odd. I have not noticed any sorts of data corruption but should the value of MASTER_LOG_POS not change with every dump from the master?

Comment: Are you running 5.5?  Pre-GTID?

Comment: Yes MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is correct. 
In your `MySQLDump` you issue a `flush-logs` command, which creates a new Binary log. 
The initial position in the binary log (after headings etc.) is 107, and always will be (unless you upgrade to a different version - then it may be something else).

Comment: Thanks, does that mean my other slaves already connected to the master will have a problem if the flush-logs command is issued?

Comment: They shouldn't do. Because `flush logs` should close the current logfile gracefully, and the slaves will then `read` that the logfile has closed and a new one started, and simply move to the new one. You can use the `mysqlbinlog` app to read the contents of the binlogs (and relay logs), and you can see the opening / closing statements if you wanted to.